# If I am willing to repeat major courses, that I passed with a D grade, will they look bad on my transcript while applying for graduate school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, undergraduate

I am a student majoring in civil engineering and I am in my  3rd year.I had a harsh beginning: I took 2 intensive courses during my first year of college after a gap semester. I didn’t perform well during my first and second year of college. I have repeated one failed major course( got a D- the second time)  and one physics course passed with a D( I got a C the next time). I have withdrawn from a surveying class during summer and retook it the next year. Recently, during the last semester of my second year I decided to work hard in order to raise my GPA and I achieved a score of 84.64 on my semester average. 
However, I am regretting and overthinking what happened during the first 2 years so much that I think that the only solution to relieve myself of the pain of thinking and blaming would be to repeat the courses that I passed with a D( 5 courses: one of them is a social elective, one an environmental chemistry core course but important for my graduate field of interest, and the three others are major courses: geology, mechanics of material and mechanics of fluid).
Which is better, to move on or to repeat these courses? Or to audit them? ( I am asking in term of graduate admissions).
My GPA is 2.92 over 4 which means 77/100. 
In my university, 80 is 3.2 over 4.
I don’t follow the lettering system

Comment: Do you actually enjoy this study? What explains all the bad grades? Would a different field make you happier?

Comment: No, actually I love the subjects..But I didn’t have the right attitude for studying for the exams. I used to procrastinate and neglect. Now, almost halfway in my curriculum( 71 units out of 143) I feel much more serious about my courses.

Comment: Please explain the letters and GPa in detail. Not everyone in the world is in your countr,

Comment: Check my post again I edited it

Comment: Note that some places replace a grade on a course that you retake with no evidence of the early grade. Others show both the old and new grades.

Comment: Actually they remain on the transcript.however, only the higher score counts  in the GPA

Comment: That policy varies from university to university.  At my university, _both_ grades count toward the GPA by default, but students can petition for a limited number of grade replacements (and even with grade replacement, both grades appear on the transcript).  But the fine details don't really matter, because applications include complete transcripts; nothing prevents the universities _you're applying to_ from recalculating your GPA using whatever protocol _they_ like.

Comment: I still don't understand the GPA numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they will look bad unless the university replaces the old grade with the new one as some do. And if you continue to get poor grades in important courses it will look worse. But there are a number of other factors that people might consider, provided you can get them to look at an application.

First, starting out on the wrong foot isn't uncommon. Nor is it a sure indicator of future failure. But, you need to turn it around.

Next, people evaluating your record are more likely to put emphasis on what you've done recently than on what you did earlier. So, re-taking the courses, not for the grades but for the knowledge can help. And not having the knowledge will be a sure block to your future. Audits are less valuable, of course, as there is no record of your performance.

Those evaluating applications for further study or for a job are looking for indicators of success. If you can show that, then you have a chance. A record of doing better recently will help, but it will also be important to have letters of recommendation from people who can honestly say that the past is past and you have a high likelihood of success in the graduate program and beyond.

On the other hand, you will be faced with stiff competition from people who haven't had a once-deficient background. It is easier for evaluators to pick people who have always seemed to be a success than someone who has struggled. The decision has less risk when you choose an all "top marks" student. But, people know, also, that such "top" students don't always succeed and some people with special motivation will, especially if they have learned to overcome a weak background.

So, the bottom line is that it isn't impossible, but it will be hard. If you can turn it around and convince your current professors that you truly have put yourself on a better path, then you have a chance.

I'd also suggest that you don't "make excuses" for the past, but face it honestly. But get on the path to success and convince others that you have.

Answer (score 2):

Of course the poor grades will look bad, especially in core courses.  As Buffy says, it's always *easier*, however short-sighted, to admit students who have been consistently successful than students whose records are more variable.

But retaking the same (or equivalent) courses and doing well would be strong evidence that you've gotten past whatever was holding you back before especially if you also have strong recommendation letters, good research results, and/or other evidence that reinforces that message.  Many admissions committee members will see that improvement positively.  Definitely not all, probably not even most, but perhaps enough.

Everybody goes through rough patches. **Everybody.** People who serve on admissions committees know that, because we've been through those rough patches ourselves.  Beating yourself up over your past failures is pointless and self-destructive.  Take responsibility, yes, but forgive yourself.  Do the best you can from where you are.

(My undergrad GPA was lower than yours.)

Comment: And you made it to a pretty demanding place.

Answer (score 0):

It will generally look better if you retake a class than if you had just left on the original grades for sure. But the main issue is that you seem to have failed quite a few (at my university, C- or lower was considered failing for major requirements, generally meaning we would need to retake the class), and it doesn't help that on some of the repeats you had grades in the C-range). Its more or less understandable if you fail one or two, especially if you have a rough start to undergraduate studies. Beyond that, you'll have a trickier problem to the point you'll need to find a way to address it, either through SOP or recommenders when applying to graduate programs, especially since you noted you have a GPA of less than 3.

Also to add on, a course you failed may be considered to be worth retaking if the course is **extremely important/relevant** for what you want to study in grad school.  But if you have taken a course and not done so well in that course but did well in a successor course that had the "failed" course as a prerequisite, then generally not so much of a need to repeat the course you failed because it shows somewhat of an upward trend (i.e. I got a C in an introductory linear algebra class, but got B or better for all future applied mathematics classes).  I'm saying this because retaking courses takes time that you could spend on other pursuits.  It's up to you to figure out the classes most worth retaking if needed and prioritize accordingly.  As others have said, gaining research experience is also important for graduate admission so you don't want to neglect that entirely, even with repeating courses.